# Image does not crop

Tags: graphics, width, crop

When I do the following:

```
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{image.jpg}
```

The space where the image should be, is correctly scaled to the size of the scaled image, but the image itself doesn't scale. So i still have a HUGE image, with the correct starting coordinate in the left bottom corner.

Any ideas why the image doesn't scale, but the space where the image should be does?

EDIT: not cropping, but scaling

Comment: Perhaps the `clip=true` option to `\includegraphics` will help. And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: adding that doesn't do anything

Comment: if `width=\textwidth` dosn't work then there is something wrong with your image. Make it available for a download to test it.

Comment: @Napje: It was just a proposition... without a MWE and the file at hand it is very difficult to make qualified propositions

Answer (score 1):

The command you're giving does not crop/trim your image.
To do that, you have to use the `trim` option of `includegraphics` like so (see [this post on texblog](http://texblog.org/2012/02/23/crop-figures-with-includegraphics/) for more info).
When you replace *left*, *bottom*, *right* and *top* by length values you see how your image is cropped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=left bottom right top, clip]{file}
    \caption{default}
    \label{default}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, it doesnt need trimming/cropping, it need to scale to the page width

Comment: This was not clear for me from your question. Please update your question with a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) including the original image if possible.